# What is the preferred way to register a .tlb on a build machine?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, activex

I have a .net solution with a C# project and a C++ project.  The C++ project is an automation server (.exe).  The C# project references an ActiveX interface produced by the C++ project (.tlb or registered interface on the machine).  This works great on a development machine as I am registering the .tlb using regtlibv12.exe in a post build event in the C++ project.  On the build machine, this fails because the service that runs the builds does not have rights to update the registry.

Is it typical to have the service that runs automated builds run as an administrator?  Is there another preferred way to do this?

I also read that regtlibv12.exe is not always installed.  Is there another way that is preferred to register a .tlb?

Comment: It the C++ project is in the same solution then you don't have a problem.  The build server will build the project, that gets the component registered and your C# project builds happily afterwards.  Apparently you are doing something else, it is not clear what.  Could be a build order problem, perhaps.

Comment: What if you registered the type lib using regtlibv12.exe on the build machine, after the C++ project completes it's build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no other way to register the type library in the build process other than using regtlibv12.exe.  I had to make sure the automated build service is an administrator and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

In a C# project just check if C++ application (automation server) is running and run it if not.

Then automation server (.exe) will register all available CLSID's in a system